# Asp.Net Using Eval Inside a style control for Progress Bar

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi Guys I have a simple aspx code below. I just wanted to add #Eval("Percent")
inside the style control. The following is the code..

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptrSizes" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
              <table id="example1" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                                <th>Supplier</th>
                               <th>Stocks Progress</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                  <td><%# Eval("Supplier") %></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="progress progress-xs progress-striped active">
                      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" style="width: 70%"></div>
                    </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>

                     </ItemTemplate>

                      <FooterTemplate>

                <thead>
                <tr>

                               <th>Supplier</th>
                               <th>Stocks Progress</th>



                </tr>
                </thead>
                          </tbody>
                          </table>
                </FooterTemplate>

                  </asp:Repeater>
```

Where am getting stacked is here i just wanted to connect it to my Database Table of the field percent

```
 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" style="width: 70%"></div>
```

Can i use something like this since am not sure if it will work

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" style='<% "Width:"+#Eval("percent")%'></div>
```

For reference this is my Sql Table Design

```
[dbo].[Table1]
Id Int, Not Null,
Name NVARCHAR MAX, NULL,
Item NVARCHAR MAX, NULL,
Percent MONEY, NULL,
```

Does datatype money affect it as percent when it comes to data binding in aspx codes...Please Help any idea i will appreciate alot Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried isolating your call to `Eval` like this? `style="width:<%# Eval("percent") %>">` I am not very familiar with the details of this syntax, but if your `<%# Eval("Supplier") %>` is working, I would expect that to work too (It should just spit out the number, unaware that it is inside of a style).

Comment: Still Does not work..